# Centering and scaling data using the polyfit function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

So I have a long list of data and for my project and I need to find a line of best fit for it. My professor has recommended centering and scaling the data using `[p,S,mu] = polyfit(x,n)`. But then when I compute the best fit line, I should be using this new data. How do I access this data? Matlab's help says that it uses a formula taking (x- mu1)/mu2. So to use the corrected x values I would just need to replace the x in `yfit1 = polyval(coef1,x)`; with `(x-mu(1)/mu(2))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.  Replace

```
yfit1 = polyval(coef1,x);
```

with

```
yfit1 = polyval(coef1,(x-mu(1))/mu(2));
```